# AS3 Crazy Drop Down Menu Jittery Issue

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, drop-down-menu

I have a few flash errors on my website. I started playing around with AS3 and created a list that expands when mouse is over and goes down when mouse is out. Kind of like a drop down menu. Problem is sometimes it acts really spastic. Anyone have any solutions?

Here is my website...
[www.allencoded.com](http://www.allencoded.com)

Below it my code..

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

stop();

FeedBox.mouseChildren=false;
ProjectBox.mouseChildren=false;

//FeedBox Tween Stuff----------------------
var feedup:Tween = new Tween(FeedBox, "y", Strong.easeOut, 560, 290, 2, true);
var feeddown:Tween = new Tween(FeedBox, "y", Strong.easeOut, 290, 560, 2, true);
FeedBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseyOnFeed);
FeedBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseyOutBox);

function mouseyOnFeed(e:Event){
    feedup.start();
}

function mouseyOutBox(e:Event){
    feeddown.start();
}


//ProjectBox Tween stuff------------------------

var projectleft:Tween = new Tween(ProjectBox, "x", Strong.easeOut, 920, 565, 2, true);
var projectright:Tween = new Tween(ProjectBox, "x", Strong.easeOut, 565, 920, 2, true);

ProjectBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseyOnProj);
ProjectBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseyOutProj);

function mouseyOnProj(e:Event){
    projectleft.start();
}

function mouseyOutProj(e:Event){
    projectright.start();
}

//BLOG BUTTON
Blog.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, toBlog);
function toBlog(e:Event){
    var blogaddy:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.allencoded.com/blog");
    navigateToURL(blogaddy);
}
```

Comment: I have used so many flash sites that this works fine on is there anyone here that has an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function mouseyOnProj(e:Event){
  projectleft.start();
  ProjectBox.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseyOnProj);
}

function mouseyOutProj(e:Event){
  projectright.start();
  ProjectBox.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseyOutProj);
}
```

i would prefer to remove events while tweening and onCompletes addEventListeners back. Btw out source tweeners performes better for tweenings.

Ask again if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be happening when the tab reaches the mouse cursor, causing the mouse to enter it before it has finished moving. Try

```
function mouseyOnProj(e:Event){
    if (!projectleft.isPlaying) projectleft.start();//
}

function mouseyOutProj(e:Event){
    if (!projectright.isPlaying) projectright.start();//
}
```

Comment: Tried this still didn't work. BTW I had to code it like this: if(!(projectright.isPlaying)) projectright.start();